# ExpandableListView child items don't get focus when touched

Tags: android, focus, touch, expandablelistview

Ok, so I wrote an ExpandableListView and subclassed BaseExpandableListAdapter... Everything works fine except I cannot get the child views to take focus when clicked.  If I use the trackball everything works fine.  But if I try to click on a child I get no feedback whatsoever.

I have tried setting android:focusable, android:focusableInTouchMode, and android:clickable (and I have also tried setting this via code) but I can't get anything to work.  Any ideas?

Here is my Adapter code:

```
public class ExpandableAppAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    private PackageManager m_pkgMgr;
    private Context m_context;
    private List<ApplicationInfo> m_groups;
    private List<List<ComponentName>> m_children;

    public ExpandableAppAdapter(Context context, List<ApplicationInfo> groups, List<List<ComponentName>> children)
    {
        m_context = context;
        m_pkgMgr = m_context.getPackageManager();
        m_groups = groups;
        m_children = children;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPos, int childPos) 
    {
        return m_children.get(groupPos).get(childPos);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPos, int childPos) 
    {
        return childPos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPos) 
    {
        return m_children.get(groupPos).size();
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPos, int childPos, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(m_context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_app_child_row, null);
        }

        ComponentName child = (ComponentName)getChild(groupPos, childPos);
        TextView txtView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_pkg_name_id);
        if (txtView != null)
            txtView.setText(child.getPackageName());

        txtView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_class_name_id);
        if (txtView != null)
            txtView.setText(child.getClassName());

        convertView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPos) 
    {
        return m_groups.get(groupPos);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() 
    {
        return m_groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPos) 
    {
        return groupPos;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPos, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(m_context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_app_group_row, null);
        }

        ApplicationInfo group = (ApplicationInfo)getGroup(groupPos);
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_selection_icon_id);
        if (imgView != null)
        {
            Drawable img = m_pkgMgr.getApplicationIcon(group);
            imgView.setImageDrawable(img);
            imgView.setMaxWidth(20);
            imgView.setMaxHeight(20);
        }

        TextView txtView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_app_name_id);
        if (txtView != null)
            txtView.setText(m_pkgMgr.getApplicationLabel(group));

        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() 
    {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPos, int childPos) 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm having similar issues trying to manage focus programatically in an ExpandedListView. Why your 'wrap_content' fix works eludes me.

Comment: Technically this should have been added as a comment and not as an answer...

Comment: I'm not sure why it works either but it works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out!

It actually had to do with my XML file rather than my adapter (I displayed the adapter to show that I was calling `setFocusableInTouchMode` when the child view was created).

The tutorial I was using (can't remember which one it was) had me set the child height to:

```
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
```

As soon as I changed it to just wrap_content everything started working fine.