# how to regain focus on a edit text when expandable list is reloaded...?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext, expandablelistview, lost-focus

I have a ExpandableListView in which i am loading custom layouts in both group and child views.

They are having some edit text fields.

When i click on the edit text, the soft keyboard  appears, that time the list is reloaded, but focus will not be on the edit text.

As a result the input i am typing is not entered in that edit text.

If i clicked on the edit text again i can enter the values.

But I want to regain its focus even after reloading the list view.

I tried with storing the last clicked view and storing it in temporary variable, `requestFocus()` on reloading, but its not working.

How to achieve this..?

here is a screen shot.

[image]

If anybody have an idea please help me..!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: its very huge, adapter has 600 lines of code. it involves 6 custom layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage the SoftInput Keyboard for your activity.

Take a look at [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Answer (score 3):

> I tried with storing the last clicked view and storing it in temporary
>   variable, requestFocus() on reloading, but its not working.

What isn't working?  Is your activity being recreated so the temporary variable is being lost?  If so, then this answer might help you.

I haven't used an ExpandableListView before, but I've had to solve a similar problem in my code.  When an orientation change happens the activity is destroyed and then recreated, so I use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` to store information that I want to preserve.

Here's some sample code:

```
  protected StoredState mStoredState;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Object data = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

    if (data == null)
    {
      // First time initialization
      mStoredState = new StoredState();
    }
    else
    {
      // StoredState data exists
      mStoredState = (StoredState)data;

      if (mStoredState.mFieldToGiveFocusTo != -1)
      {
        // Give focus to the field that had focus before the
        // activity was recreated
        View viewToFocus = findViewById(mStoredState.mFieldToGiveFocusTo);
        viewToFocus.requestFocus();
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
  {
    return mStoredState;
  }

  /**
   * Class to store the information about this activity when the orientation
   * is changed
   */
  private static class StoredState
  {
    int mFieldToGiveFocusTo;

    private StoredState()
    {
      mFieldToGiveFocusTo = -1;
    }
  }
```

Then you just need to set `mStoredState.mFieldToGiveFocusTo` when the user first touches the EditText.

Comment: My activity is not creating again...! in the same activity the list is reloading.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with calling `requestFocus()` inside `onCreate()` or `onResume()`. I was able to solve this by setting the focus with a slight delay. Something like this might work for you:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                viewToFocus.requestFocus();

            }
        }, 100);
```

I think the root of the problem might be that the AndroidFramework sets the Focus after onResume() is processed. So that's why a delay might help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find the answer here:
[ExpandableListView child items don't get focus when touched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651818/expandablelistview-child-items-dont-get-focus-when-touched)

This guy has an issue that sounds the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

After the listView is expanded, you gain force gain focus on the editText by adding this line,

editText.requestFocus();