# How to avoid jumping of a layout in a relative layout which is given allignParentButton = true...?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-edittext

I have a Relative layout, which has two items, one is list another is custom layout.

In list view edit texts are there. when user clicks on the edit text soft keyboard pops up.

Than time the custom layout will come on the top of the key board,

which gives my very less space to enter values.

How to avoid this behaviour, is there any solution with linear layout....?

Here is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_top_bg" android:orientation="vertical">

    <include android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation2" layout="@layout/bottom_navign_other"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp" android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />


    <ExpandableListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_top_bg" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:listSelector="#00000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp" android:layout_marginRight="4dp"        
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomNavigation2">
    </ExpandableListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance...!

Comment: Try, this in manifest file current activity tag <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|"adjustPan>

Comment: Thank you..! its working as expected but, the soft keyboard is poping up in the begining itself. I want to pop up the soft keyboard whenever the user clicks on the edit text. How to do that.

Comment: remove "stateVisible" from that tag. just like, <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> and let me know what happen.

Comment: I answered on that question. Look at that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [android:windowSoftInputMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Comment: hi, answer the same in one of my other question. which i started 50 bounty. but your answer solved both of my problems. So you are one who that i can reward with that bounty. here is the link           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848037/how-to-regain-focus-on-a-edit-text-when-expandable-list-is-reloaded/7954782#7954782  answer as soon as possible. its ending tomorrow.